# Redirecting within popup window - sharepoint

Tags: 2007

sharepoint provides a method called "commonShowModalDialog" which is used to show a popup window. i am on the popup window now, i need to redirect to another page within the popup window. is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use Javascript to close the current dialog and open a new dialog with the new URL - maybe using "window.parent"

Or maybe [SPUtility.Redirect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.redirect%28v=office.12%29.aspx) can help?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the javascript

```
window.location.href = "URL"
```

inside the modal dialog; this will use the context of the open modal dialog to navigate to the new page.

Comment: then it is opening in new window. i need to redirect in the same window

Comment: Right, that's because it's using a get request. Please see http://shaneosullivan.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/navigating-in-an-ie-modal-dialog/

Comment: window.location.href would use the existing browser window, not a new one. Is that not what you want? When you  say same window, so you mean same browser window or same dialog "window"?

Comment: Jaap (hi mate!) - it's a function of the dodgy modal window model that IE6 :( uses. See the above article. Window.location.href would normally work but not in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you want to steer away from this legacy approach to showing dialogs. If you are on SharePoint 2010 a better choice is to use the dialog API.

A good walkthrough can be found on MSDN Blogs at:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jfrost/how-to-display-a-sharepoint-dialog-from-ribbon-button-and-get-selected-item-context)

Wouter

Comment: Darn it, I now see the tag 'SharePoint 2007'. Sigh!